# Transaction with unparsed input address ? What does it means?

Tags: transactions, address

I just see [this transaction](https://testnet.blockexplorer.com/tx/441705020bd6332a9de0ff435a3c144f58d50d70eba7366cdaa5dfd02ca74ccb) which is special : one of input address is spending a valid amount… But why is it unparsed ? Why no ScriptSig while stil being valid ?

Also what’s the purpose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output being spent is a native segwit output. If you look at the [transaction](https://testnet.blockexplorer.com/tx/95f4b7304ac990432090f3db003f00b8a954a33e325ab3686018f936f825dc6d) that created it, you get `0014644a61cf83439e53b5dd413bec63c98c9e39c107` for the lock script, which is a native segwit p2wpkh output.

Spending a purely segwit output requires no value to be set for the scriptSig (unlike for a p2sh-p2wpkh).

The address is shown as unparsed as Insight has not been updated to recognize bech32 addresses.